# Connecting to MySQL only once in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to MySQL only once, as instructed by others here.

```
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$get_projects = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE user = ? ORDER BY weight DESC");
$get_projects->bind_param('i', $sessionUser);
$result = $get_projects->execute();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // stuff
```

This gets

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

My old code is like this, and works

```
$get_projects = Database::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE user = ? ORDER BY weight DESC");
$get_projects->bind_param('i', $sessionUser);
    if ($result = $get_projects->execute())
        //stuff
```

Why isn't this working as expected?

More info:

```
$sessionUser = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

This is defined in a separate function. But hard coding doesn't work, like so

```
$get_projects = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE user = 1 ORDER BY weight DESC");
// $get_projects->bind_param('i', 1);
$result = $get_projects->execute();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_projects))
```

Note I put `mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_projects)` as suggested below.

Comment: Check, what error mysql gives to you after executing the query

Comment: Where's `$par` defined?

Comment: Your mixing PDO and mysqli together.

Comment: @Xatenev: uh, mysqli supports prepared statements, does it via $dbhandle->prepare() as well: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @user3733120 Call mysqli_error after the query in the else branch: http://jp1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: So now it went from `$par` to `$sessionUser` - I'm assuming you're using sessions. How/where is `$sessionUser` defined?

Comment: Note: changed the question a bit. Sorry about that. Had two different functions as examples, now they're the same one.

Comment: You didn't answer my question in the latter part of my comment above.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's a real question to me. @Fred -ii- It's defined in a function called `Tasks::get_globals();` but hardcoding the value also does not work, so I don't think it's the issue.

Comment: @user3733120 Is `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe so. I am using PHP-LOGIN to handle that. If i do `$get_projects->bind_param('i', $a = 1);` instead (so no SESSION stuff), the same thing happens.

Comment: @user3733120 I'm not entirely sure about this, but I don't think you can do `$a = 1` in `bind_param('i', $a = 1)`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` (if you're not already doing so), while making sure that php.ini file has display_errors set to 1 and not 0, and see if it yields anything more. @user3733120

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see some new errors in other places and I'm examining to see if they are related, but my first thought is they aren't.

Comment: @user3733120 Error messages can indeed be helpful, related or not, so it's best to have error reporting "on". Have a look at Bill's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = $get_projects->execute();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // stuff
```

The `execute()` method does *not* return a mysqli_result resource.

The `execute()` method returns a boolean, either true or false, indicating whether the statement execution was successful or an error occurred. So it's incorrect to pass that return value to `mysqli_fetch_result()`. You understandably get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Instead, use `get_result()` from the statement resource and start fetching from that.

Example:

```
$success = $get_projects->execute();
if (!$success) {
    // die() may not be how you want to report errors, this is just an example
    die($db->error);
}

$result = $get_projects->get_result();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // stuff
```

This may seem like a superfluous step, i.e. why doesn't execute() return a result? Because not all statements you can execute *have* a result. You could be executing an INSERT or a CREATE TABLE or something else. Only statements like SELECT and SHOW and CALL have result sets.

**Note:** the `get_result()` method requires the [mysqlnd driver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php), which is optional in PHP 5.3 and enabled by default in PHP 5.4. If you're using an older version of PHP than that, it's time to upgrade!

Comment: I think this has put me in the right direction. Thank you very much!

Comment: *Hm...* remember what you said the other day about the "who could that DV come from?"; I upvoted Bill, so you can be sure that -1 didn't come from me, but from something that's "crawling" about, or should I say "slithering"? . cheers ;-)

Comment: @YourCommonSense is ruining this site for everyone.

Comment: @BillKarwin He sure is. Yet, without mentioning any names, the least someone could do is write a comment about the DV. If someone is too lazy to type a comment and is easier to just click a mere mouse button, then evidently the hand is to be served for another purpose ;-) I think you have a pretty good idea as to what I meant by that lol (`not` aimed at you of course). Let's just say the "palm sisters" play a big part in that person's life.

Comment: @BillKarwin In my humble opinion the site could do more to enforce a kinder atmosphere while easing up on the strict question rules.

Comment: Hmmm... For a someone who registered just today, this guy looks too familiar with "strict question rules". Which makes me think he encountered with them in the past...

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, I have.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Although the problem in the question body is not a real one (as it seems you either cannot tell if your code is working or cannot copy and paste it - it is unclear from your question), here goes an answer for the title, because of its weight.

```
class Database
{
    private static $db;

    function connect()
    {
        if (static::$db === NULL)
        {
            static::$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        }
        return $db;
    }
}
```

having written this way it will connect only once, no matter how many times it is called

Comment: Thanks a lot for rephrasing your answer. I'm note sure this fixes my particular problem but it's relevant to the title and I'll implement it.

Comment: It won't fix your particular problem for sure. It's not for you actually at all, but for the future readers who may come being misled by the question title.

Comment: Well I'm sure they and I appreciate it. But it comes off kind of rude to ignore the whole body of the post. Just saying how it's perceived.

Comment: As soon as you learn how to write consistent questions, people won't ignore them - I promise.

Comment: Some very kind people helped me above. Just wanted to say thanks for rephrasing the answer and the helpful code. We all have bad days, hope to see you around and in a better mood. :)